# Counting problem - verification please?

Tags: combinatorics

A question we did in class asks: "In how many ways can we put 4 girls and 4 boys on a row (so order matters) so that a certain girl and a certain boy are always seated next to each other, and no 2 people of the same gender are seated next to each other?"

Everyone says its $4*2*(3!)^2$ but I think it is $7*2*(3!)^2$.
Let's say the row begins with a girl from left to right, then we can move the boy and the girl along this row seven times. Either the girl is on position 1, 3, 5 or 7 and for positions 3, 5, and 7, the boy can be seated either to the left or right of her, so it's 7 possibilities. We take $(3!)^2$ because the boys and the girls can be exchanged among themselves in $3!$ ways each (whether they are seated on uneven or even spots is determined by whether the row starts with a boy or a girl). Multiply by 2 because the row can also start with a boy.
Is this correct?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: I agree.  It seems that they used the number $4$ instead because they picked the set of the special girl, and assumed that the special boy must always *follow* her, but it doesn't account for situations where the special boy *precedes* her (as you point out).  Compare this problem to the one: "In how many ways can we put 4 girls and 4 boys into four loveseats (couches that sit two people) such that a certain girl and certain boy are always seated next to eachother in the same loveseat, and no 2 people of the same gender are seated next to eachother (even across loveseats)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Here' sanother way to think about it:

Let the boy and girl together be a "pair".

The pair can be in position (1,2) or (2,3) or ... or (7,8): 7 possibilities.

The pair can be boy first or girl first - so multiply by 2.

The "boy" and "girl slots are now determined by the position of the boy nad the girl from the first pair. The other three boys can be placed in the remaining "boy" slots in $3!$ ways, and similarly for the girls.

That gives you your answer of $7 \times 2 \times 3! \times 3!$

Comment: Isn't that the same as mine? :p

Comment: Yes - I thought you wanted verification...?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant this was another way to prove it